# Display mail on the basis of the subject

Tags: vba, outlook

On a daily basis I receive a mail which is comprised of tables and text.

I want to detect the mail on the basis of the mail subject and copy data of the table to an Excel sheet.

Comment: If you search stack overflow you will find lots of examples

Comment: It would be great if you can share the link.

Comment: What does the email body looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article which explains the basics.

The [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686.aspx) event of the Application class is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The EntryIDsCollection string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893.aspx) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously. Y

You may check the `Subject` property and export the data from the message body if required. For that you can automate Excel from Outlook. See [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/219151) for more information.